# identityserver4 Hybrid follow without competed login

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an API that needs to secure allowing 3rd party asp.net core MVC web application to request an access token and use this access token to request the secured API.

i created HybridAndClientCredentials client on the identity server

```
            ClientId = "testclient",
            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("password".Sha256())
            },
            RedirectUris = {"http://127.0.0.1:55950",
                            "http://localhost/testLogin",
                            "https://localhost:44322/",
                            "https://localhost:44302/",
                            "https://localhost:44303/signin-oidc"},
            RequireConsent = false,
            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "roles" , IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile}
```

and MVC client as showing in identity server 4 documentation

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Constants.Authority;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientSecret = "password";
                    options.ClientId = "testclient";

                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    //options.Scope.Add("email");
                    //options.Scope.Add("resource1.scope1");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                    options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce", "iat", "c_hash");

                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                    };
                });
```

it's working but the user appears to be logged in the MVC application all I want is the access token to be used in calling the secured API also I don't want to use [authorize] attribute on the MVC client to redirect the user to identity server login page.

Answer (score 1):

Something in the MVC application must to trigger a challenge to the OpenIDconnect handler, that starts the process to authenticate the user. As a result the user is logged in and you get access to the tokens.

Using a **[Authorize]** attribute is one way to trigger a challenge, or to do it manually using code like:

```
    public async Task Login()
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" });
    }
```